# Are my boiled eggs ok to eat?

Tags: hard-boiled-eggs

I boiled eggs late last night & fell asleep waiting on them to cool so I could peel them & refrigerate. When i woke up this morning the water was cool. Are they ok to eat?

Answer (score 2):

The FDA does not consider this safe.  Here are their relevant recommendations for serving and storing cooked eggs:

> - Serve cooked eggs (such as hard-boiled eggs and fried eggs) and egg-containing foods (such as such as quiches and soufflés) immediately after cooking. Cooked eggs and egg dishes may be refrigerated for serving later but should be thoroughly reheated to 165° F before serving.
> - Never leave cooked eggs or egg dishes out of the refrigerator for more than 2 hours or for more than 1 hour when temperatures are above 90° F. Bacteria that can cause illness grow quickly at warm temperatures (between 40° F and 140° F).

[What You Need to Know About Egg Safety](https://www.fda.gov/food/buy-store-serve-safe-food/what-you-need-know-about-egg-safety)

Comment: so we've been poisoning ourselves every easter then, when eating cold easter eggs for days?

Comment: @ths You’ve been violating the FDA’s recommendations, yes. Those recommendations are intended to be simple and conservative; they don’t indicate situations which the FDA expects will *definitely* harm you.

Comment: I often bring hard boiled eggs with some other food when I go hiking, often I postpone lunch until 6PM or later, therefore I keep them out of the fridge for almost an entire day and I never saw any sign of spoiling.

Comment: @ths and FluidCode, you might consider reading this page about what "food safety" means, here on Seasoned Advice: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info

Comment: @ths FDA: "Easter eggs should be hard-boiled before coloring. Do NOT eat them after hiding or playing with them. Bacteria and viruses picked up on the shells can be transferred to the edible part of the egg."

Comment: that seems absurdly over cautious.