# Are hard boiled eggs safe to eat after hours out of the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, eggs

I left hard boiled eggs in cold water over night are they still good to eat?   The have the egg odor to them

Comment: And for hard-boiled eggs specifically: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/120884/are-my-boiled-eggs-ok-to-eat/

Answer (score -4):

It depends just how long they are out. In truth, I often take raw eggs out the night before baking so that they come to room temperature. As a child, I remember eating hard-boiled eggs from our Easter basket--sometimes several days later with no problem. This is my "take" on eggs after 72 years!

The USDA definitely disagrees with me, and attached is the US Government's "scientific" view:
https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/How-long-can-you-keep-hard-cooked-eggs

Ultimately, trust your nose: If it smells fine, eat it (the egg, not your nose).

Comment: Smell is not a reliable indicator of food safety.  It is, perhaps, a better indicator of spoilage, but really not a useful food safety tool. The problem with using your nose is that, more often than not, food borne pathogens don't create off-aromas.  Another challenge is that personal experience...luck...is not a helpful way to think about food safety either.  Best to go with the science (deliberately not in quotes). :-)